# Tuning Regex to tune out email addresses but keep certain user names

Tags: regex

I need help in tuning a regex that is looking for certain matches on usernames and passwords that should not be passed in the clear. The usernames have a certain pattern to follow, 6 char in length, some can start with a letter of m, and other single letters. The passwords can be 6 - 12 characters in length. Not really looking for a password per-say, but something after a hit on a key username pattern that matches the hunt pattern. This regex code is pretty close. On my internal system testing, it does indeed hit on username/passwords the expected way with no issues, however, on regex101.com, and internally, it also hits on email addresses, and I don't want it too. TIA for any and all help.

Here is the Regex.

> `(([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\b|assword|username|[mts]\d{5}\b|[a-zA-Z0-9\_.+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+)[^\>:\/\\.0-9]{1,8}[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*\_\-\+\=]{6,12})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*\_\-\+\=]{6,12}[^:\/\\.0-9]{1,8}([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\b|assword|username|[mts]\d{5}\b|[a-zA-Z0-9\_.+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+))`

Here is a test I send through internal testing systems and also in part what I run through regex101.com

```
m12345 u/gibberish12
m23456 pa$$werd
m34567 #password20
m08943 $secretstuf
mailmon@abc1234
mirror@abc1234
```

The following is an example of the type of email address it hits on, and shouldn't and this needs to get tuned out and keep the other hits:

```
<abcdefghijklmnopq@test.domainname.com-mail.com>
```

Comment: Tip: `[a-zA-Z0-9\_]` can be simplified to `\w`. Also, `[\_\+\=\.\<\>\/]` is the same as `[_+=.<>/]` because most characters in a character class don't need escaping (`-` does though, unless first or last). Cleaning up your regex will make it easier to read and debug.

Comment: In going back, after running the code through, it still manages to hit on the email address. So with the below regex code, it works great, other than it too picks up on the portion of the username in the email address, is there a way to have a not equal too, if it finds an '@' after the username search, that way to eliminate email address hits, and stay focused on only username?  (\b|[^a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}|[mst][0-9]{5})([^a-zA-Z0-9]|\b)

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 1):

You must have at least one mandatory space character.

try this:

> `(([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\b|assword|username|[mts]\d{5}\b|[a-zA-Z0-9\_.+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+)\s[^\>:\/\\.0-9]{1,7}[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*\_\-\+\=]{6,11})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*\_\-\+\=]{6,12}[^:\/\\.0-9]{1,7}\s([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\b|assword|username|[mts]\d{5}\b|[a-zA-Z0-9\_.+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+))`

I replace the : [^>:/\.0-9]{1,**8**}

to: **\s**[^>:/\.0-9]{1,**7**}  / [^>:/\.0-9]{1,**7**}**\s** (depended on the two alternatievs)

Comment: Thanks, this is money, exactly what was to get accomplished, as I didn't want to loose the code that find emails, but it eliminate the email hit. Many email addresses have a portion of the username, so that was what needed to get tuned out.